# QML listview Transition does not work for C++ Model

Tags: qml, qlistview

I have tried this example for add animation.It works

```
 ListView {
    width: 240; height: 320
    model: ListModel {}

    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 100; height: 30
        border.width: 1
        color: "lightsteelblue"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: name
        }
    }

    add: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { property: "opacity"; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 400 }
        NumberAnimation { property: "scale"; from: 0; to: 1.0; duration: 400 }
    }

    displaced: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; duration: 400; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce }
    }

    focus: true
    Keys.onSpacePressed: model.insert(0, { "name": "Item " + model.count })
}
```

When new record is inserted in model , add anim works perpeftly.But I want to refer model to C++ list like:

```
model:mymodel.list
```

When I add new record to list , listmodel is updated but **add animation not take effect**

I Find Solution by using QAbstractItemModel

Comment: How do you expose the C++ list to QML? If you use [`QQmlListProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html) you cannot use `Trasition`. That is because with this class whole list is being updated at once, even if only one element changes. I believe you can achieve what you need with [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel)

Comment: @FilipHazubski , I have a class with two property. I have created a list like QList<QObject*> mylist . mylist.appent(new MyClass(param 1 , param 2);

Comment: How do you expose this `QList` to QML then? You can attach the code.

Comment: @FilipHazubski I have solved with QAbstractItemList.Thanks for your advice :D

Comment: Good to know :) Please consider posting your solution as an answer and accepting it